# Android: Weird openStream on 4.0 ICS

Tags: java, android, http, inputstream

I try to get text from website that I show in a textview.

I Use:

```
try {
         textUrl = new URL("http://google.com");
         BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
         String StringBuffer;
               String stringText = "";
         while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
          stringText += StringBuffer;
         }
               bufferReader.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

if I set  `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion>` to 15 (ICS 4.0.3) then my app crashes.
if I delete that line ( means that target is 1.6 I guess) then it works fine but my app is scales weird on my phone.

Logcat just tells me that it cannot start Activity.

//Pew Labs

LOG:

```
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:703)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:350)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:540)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.pewlabs.sunds.Food.downloadFile(Food.java:64)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.pewlabs.sunds.Food.onCreate(Food.java:45)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4524)
03-21 17:12:42.874: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
```

Comment: Post the LogCat error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NetworkOnMainThreadException` that was thrown is trying to tell you that you are doing network operations on the main UI Thread. You need to be doing them in a separate `Thread`, or a simple convention is to use a `AsyncTask` or `Loader`.

Comment: I tried Async but I i guess it loads. but I have bo clue how to display text with TextView because async cannot controll my TextView that is in main Activity

Comment: Use the onPostExecute() method on AsyncTask for posting back onto the UI Thread.

Comment: It is always called, the problem is probably with your implementation of it.

Comment: A clear example can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: hmm. Probably. Im fetching data from a website then i want to display it in the activity. But Asynctask doesnt extend my activity therefor I cannot setText on my textView from asynctask